# How to delete a Scheduled task folder with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-task

I need to delete a scheduled task *folders* on a lot of machines, ideally with PowerShell. I couldn't find anything on how to do that - it seems like the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/) covers everyting but folders.

Did I miss someting?

Comment: It looks like deleting the registry key here would work: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\PathToFolder`

Comment: This is short, hard ... and works.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can't do that with the Task Scheduler cmdlet.

However, someone posted the solution on StackOverflow: [How to delete folder from Task Scheduler with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56926116/2879900) :

```
$scheduleObject = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$scheduleObject.connect()
$rootFolder = $scheduleObject.GetFolder("\")
$rootFolder.DeleteFolder("My Task Folder",$null)
```

The documentation about `DeleteFolder` is available here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskfolder-deletefolder

Comment: Yes, that works. But before it does, the task folder needs to be emptied. And that again needs some syntax I am not aware of. In batch, to delete all tasks in a folder "test", I would use <code> for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('schtasks /tn \test\ ^|findstr /v "TaskName ==== Folder"') do schtasks /delete /tn \test\%%a /f</code>

Comment: @BerndSchwanenmeister Powershell equivalent: `Get-ScheduledTask | where TaskPath -eq "\MyPath\" | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false`